# React Native/Jest TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined - testing with jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to create a test in an application with jest and this is some lines of my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {...} from 'react-native';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

class CreateProduct extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.keyboardHeight = new Animated.Value(0);
  this.imageHeight = new Animated.Value(199);
  this.state = {
    isButtonsHidden: false,
    title: '',
    price: '',
    description: '',
    isDialogVisible: false,
    messageError: '',
  };
}

_goBack = async () => {
  const {state} = this.props.navigation;
  var token = state.params ? state.params.token : undefined;

  this.props.navigation.navigate('MyProducts', {token:token});
}
```

I want to test the navigation:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('MyProducts', {token:token});
```

Now this is the attempt to test:

```
describe('Testing navigation', () =>{

  let wrapper = null
  const spyNavigate = jest.fn()
  const props = {
    navigation:{
        navigate: spyNavigate
    }
  }
  const params = {
      token: 'randomToken'
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<CreateProduct {...props}/>)
    wrapper.setState({params: params})
  })

  it('should test navigation', () => {
  wrapper.instance()._goBack(params)
  expect(spyNavigate).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

But I'm receiving [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEV9d.png).

I'm assuming that there is an error with the way I'm passing the `const params`. Can you help me telling what's the best way I can do this to simulate a token and that way I can navigate in the screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rootcause is your `_goBack` is `async`. But you don't await till it ends before running `expect`. Even more: jest also does not wait `_goBack` to finish so you don't even see an error

> Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

that happens because you don't mock `state` in `navigation.params`.

To work with async code there are [2 different approaches in Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous): either returning Promise from the `it()` or running `done()` callback manually(it's passed as 1st argument in `it()`).

I'll picking 2nd since it allows us also await until `goBack` is finished before running `expect`:

```
describe('Testing navigation', () => {

  let wrapper = null
  const spyNavigate = jest.fn()
  const props = {
    navigation: {
      navigate: spyNavigate,
      state: {}
    }
  }
  const params = {
    token: 'randomToken'
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<CreateProduct {...props} />)
    wrapper.setState({ params: params })
  })

  it('should test navigation', async () => {
    await wrapper.instance()._goBack(params)
    expect(spyNavigate).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

Or without using `async/await` it would look like

```
  it('should test navigation', () => {
    return wrapper.
        instance()._goBack(params).
        then(() => expect(spyNavigate).toHaveBeenCalled());
  })
```

that looks messy

Or using `done()` callback

```
  it('should test navigation', (done) => {
      wrapper.
        instance()._goBack(params).
        then(() => expect(spyNavigate).toHaveBeenCalled()).
        then(done);
  })
```

Comment: it is error to me --->     > 84 |     expect(spyNavigate).toHaveBeenCalled();

Comment: @samira I doubt you have exactly the same code as OP had back then in 2018. It might be "shallow() does not trigger useEffect()", wrong selector while triggering navigaton or incorrect name for prop with a spy. Better ask new question with providing full context.